# how to customize datatable in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using datatables in my bootstrap admin panel. Now i want to customize it but can't find its files and code.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6">
    <div id="DataTables_Table_0_length" class="dataTables_length">
      <label>
        <select name="DataTables_Table_0_length" size="1" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0">
          <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option><option value="25">25</option>
          <option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option>
        </select> records per page
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="span6">
    <div class="dataTables_filter" id="DataTables_Table_0_filter">
      <label>Search: <input type="text" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I got above code from firebug, where can i find these div. i want to add float right in search div so that it can align right to table

Comment: It is usually at the right side, could you show a screenshot of your table?

Answer (score 0):

The search div is `.dataTables_filter`, you can add necessary styling to this class in css ( like `float:right`)

Comment: where can i find these div. in which files are these div located

Comment: this div is in the code you posted in question, you should just go to css and add `.dataTables_filter{float:right;}`